# ¿Es cierto que la palabra "carajo" designaba una canastilla en el palo mayor de las naves?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado

Normalmente la palabra [carajo](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=carajo) es empleada en frases con connotaciones despectivas, pero acabo de ver una imagen en la cual se dice que antiguamente se utilizaba con otros fines.

[image]

> Se le llamaba "carajo" a la pequeña canastilla que se encontraba en lo alto del palo mayor de las naves antiguas. Cuando un marinero cometía alguna falta, se le mandaba al carajo como castigo. Por eso, cuando queremos perder de vista a alguien usamos la expresión "vete al carajo".

¿Alguien tiene referencias al respecto?

Comment: Interesante saber que la palabra proviene del mar y ha modificado su significado

Answer (score 9, accepted):

La palabra `carajo` no tiene una procedencia segura, por lo que el propio Diccionario académico indica que es "de origen incierto".

De igual manera el origen de la expresión es incierto<sup>1</sup>, y aunque incluso en algunas webs "de confianza", como [etimologías de chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?carajo) lo apoyan, otras muchas lo desmienten.

La historieta en cuestión dice que a nadie le gustaba estar en la canastilla esa, que era un lugar peligroso, expuesto al frío, la lluvia y el sol y donde era más fácil marearse. Los marineros que no cumplían bien sus tareas terminaban siendo "mandados al carajo" como "castigo" para que escarmentasen.

Por tanto, explican que "mandar a alguien al carajo" era mandarles a ese lugar incómodo y de ahí la expresión.

Sin embargo [esta otra web](http://www.eltiempo.com/archivo/documento/CMS-13760642) explica que esa historia sobre el origen es muy popular y extendida, pero **falsa** (y eso explica que no puedas encontrar en el diccionario en la entrada de `carajo` una referencia a la canastilla del mástil del barco).

> Sin embargo, nunca existió en las embarcaciones sitio alguno al que le dijeran ‘carajo’. A los marineros díscolos simplemente se los encerraba en el calabozo, a pan y agua. Más agua que pan. Y la famosa canastilla, que sí existe, es en realidad el puesto del vigía y en castellano se llama **‘cofa’**.

---

1- En el Diccionario académico, la voz *carajo* nunca ha tenido el significado de ‘puesto del vigía de los galeones’. La primera vez que se incluye esta voz en el Diccionario académico es en 1983, pero **con otros significados**.

El Departamento de «Español al día» de la Real Academia Española, ha encontrado el significado de `carajo` como `cofa` **solo** en el [Diccionario náutico abreviado](http://usuarios.arnet.com.ar/maf_lcd/gponcio/diccio/diccio.htm), de G. Poncio, L. Ballester, R. Nicotra y A. Will. Si esa única entrada es suficiente como para validar el origen de la expresión puede ser motivo de debate, debido a la escasez de evidencias (Habría que ver qué fuentes usan estos autores para atribuir a "carajo" el mismo significado que "cofa").

Aquí hay otro enlace de interés sobre el  [origen de la palabra “Carajo”](https://nauticajonkepa.wordpress.com/2010/12/21/origen-de-la-palabra-carajo/).

Comment: Ud no ha excluido la interpretación que se propuso ahí.  Las palabras podrían tener mucha variación dentro de Latinoamerica.  En mi país **bicho** es claramente el órgano masculino y en otros lugares es un animál.  Aquí uno se refiere a etimología de Chile, otro a un fuente peninsular, yo me refiero al Caribe.   Jamás yo podría referir a un tipo de **huevón** que sería un insulto, de verdad.

Comment: @johnmangual, este usuario quería contrastar la veracidad de esa historia sobre el origen de la expresión y su relación con la canastilla de los barcos. Creo que mi respuesta contesta a esa pregunta. No excluyo ni incluyo acepciones del término. No digo que carajo no sea un insulto (y el OP no está preguntando si lo es o dónde), pero desde luego no es una parte de barco (si lo fuera, tendría su entrada y explicación correspondiente en el DRAE) en ninguna de las variedades del español.

Comment: Una nota sobre la respuesta: cuando digo que Etimologías de Chile es una web de confianza, lo digo en serio. Yo he usado muchas veces la web y los contenidos me parecen serios y en su mayor parte trabajados. Sin embargo, como cualquier otro recurso "no oficial" tiene sus fallos, y esta en particular se les ha colado. Si yo hubiese llegado primero a Etimologías de Chile, nunca me habría preocupado de validar esa historia, y la habría dado por buena. En este caso estaba contrastando, y se ve que esta se les ha colado (han puesto varias aportaciones de usuarios, sin más y ahí cada uno ya valida).

Comment: Disculpa. Sólo voy comentar que el Español tiene mucha variación y regionalismos. Chile (y Buenos Aires) ambos son notorios por eso. En mi caso, sigo aprendiendo hasta los de mi propia región.

Comment: En el diccionario de americanismos una de las acepciones de _carajo_ es lugar muy lejano ¿Vendrá de ahí mandar a alguien al carajo?¿O será al revés?

Comment: Discusión relacionada: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39698239#39698239 en la que referencian a [Origen de la palabra “Carajo”](https://nauticajonkepa.wordpress.com/2010/12/21/origen-de-la-palabra-carajo/) con respuesta de la RAE indicando que el _Diccionario náutico abreviado_ sí contiene el  término _carajo_ como sinónimo de _cofa_.

Comment: @fedorqui, gracias, actualizada la respuesta

Comment: Acabo de darme cuenta de que por aquí se utiliza a veces la expresión *el carajo de la vela* de forma similar, no sé de donde sale eso y si tiene algo que ver con todo este asunto, investigaré un poco sobre ello.

Comment: @blonfu ¿dónde es "por aquí"?

Comment: @fedorqui la verdad que lo suele decir mi padre, no sé si se dice por aquí en general XD. Aquí es Bilbao

Answer (score 5):

Por lo que he visto en el NTLLE, en todos los diccionarios en que aparece *carajo* (desde 1505 en adelante) el único significado es "pene", "miembro viril", etc. Ninguno recoge una acepción como la que indicas.

Comment: Qué es NTLLE? Pudiera usted adicionar una referencia por favor?

Comment: A lo mejor no aparece otra referencia a su significa porque pudiera ser una palabra específica de la navegación de tiempos antiguos?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer NTLLE es el Nuevo tesoro lexicográfico de la lengua española. Puedes encontrar más info sobre diccionarios en [Resources for learning Spanish](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/a/2515/1674)

Comment: Why do they give points to an answer based only on unconfirmed fonts while yours is final?

Comment: @JohnB Because you give point if the answer is usefull to you, is based in a personal opinion, maybe this answer is not usefull to you but its for other users

Answer (score 1):

Sin duda, la palabra "carajo" tiene el significado de "miembro viril", como ocurre con su equivalente portugués "caralho".

Es poco verosímil que alguien quiera decir "canastilla" cuando está enojado o se golpea un dedo con el martillo. Sí tiene relación bastante obvia con el mástil de un barco, también llamado "verga".

Wiktionary [define así a la palabra "carajo"](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/carajo).

> Órgano eréctil que presenta el macho de los mamíferos [...] en el que desembocan los conductos del tracto genitourinario.

Comment: Hola Victorious, muy buena respuesta. En la parte que enlazas a Wiktionary, preferimos que copies las partes relevantes de los enlaces, para que si algún día dejen de funcionar sigamos teniendo la información. Bienvenido/a a [spanish.se], esperamos verte con frecuencia :)

Comment: No creo que siempre la palabra carajo este relacionada con el miembro viril, al menos en Cuba no, pudieras decir en que zonas guarda la semejanza?

Comment: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caralho

Answer (score 0):

Carajo viene de la palabra "carallo" (Galicia, España) es un vulgarismo para referirse al órgano masculino. Cuando se mandaba a un marinero al carajo era por haber cometido alguna falta, era un castigo. **Se llama carajo a la canastilla que había en el palo mayor de las carabelas y es la parte más inestable de la embarcación**. Cuando bajaban de allí los castigados, normalmente estaban mareados y descompuestos, si consideraba que esa actitud era exagerada se decía que "no vales un carajo" eres débil que no aguantas.

[https://exponav.org/el-carajo-de-la-vela/`](https://exponav.org/el-carajo-de-la-vela/%60)
`