# ¿Por qué "carajillo" (diminutivo de carajo) es una bebida alcohólica con café caliente?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, significado, comida, vulgaridades

A raíz de [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19296/significado-de-la-palabra-carajo/19297#19297) me he tropezado con [**carajillo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7PGHxNA):

> Del dim. de *carajo*.
>   1. m. Bebida que se prepara generalmente añadiendo una bebida alcohólica fuerte al café caliente.

[**Carajo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7PHLd6o) es

> De or. inc.
>   1. m. malson. **miembro viril**.

¿Cómo se ha establecido esa relación entre el "diminutivo del miembro viril" y la "bebida alcohólica fuerte con café caliente"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De acuerdo a [etimologías de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?carajillo):

> La palabra **carajillo** es usada para referirse a un café con *picardía*, o sea con un poco de licor.

La web explica que la palabra viene de cuando tropas españolas invadieron Cuba y debido a la falta de suministros tuvieron que tirar de recursos locales para el café y el licor (ron). Como la mezcla de ambos les daba "coraje" (valentía), la frase común antes del combate era

> "Vamos a coger **corajillo**

y de ahí la reverberación "corajillo-carajillo"

[Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carajillo) aclara que el origen es incierto, pero alude a la misma anécdota que la otra referencia.

> Su origen es desconocido y quizá se remonta a la época en la que Cuba era colonia española y los soldados combinaban café con ron para coger "corajillo", de coraje, y de ahí, carajillo

Así que `carajillo` es más una corrupción del diminutivo de `coraje` que el diminutivo de `carajo`.

Comment: Según el [fichero general](http://www.rae.es/recursos/banco-de-datos/fichero-general) de la RAE, la palabra "carajillo" tiene otros significados regionales como el nombre de un pez, un chico que presume de mayor, o un insulto ("¿Dónde está el maldito carajillo? ¡Traédmelo que lo mato!") aplicado generalmente a gente de baja estatura. Puede que la reverberación se produjera en algún sitio en los que la palabra ya se usara con alguno de estos otros significados.

Comment: Pero a) la etimología propuesta (a partir de "**corajillo**") discrepa de la de la RAE ("**diminutivo de carajo**") y b) las primeras veces que el Diccionario de la Lengua lo recoge, habla de que el licor que se añade es "generalmente **coñac o anís**"; ninguna mención del ron.

Comment: Igualmente en el fichero general de la RAE, en los casos en los que "carajillo" aparece como bebida y se menciona su composición, ésta es **coñac** o **anís**.

Comment: @user, buen punto, pero si la RAE dice que "carajillo" es diminutivo de "carajo", está dando entonces la etimología de la la palabra? Pregunto, porque hasta donde yo sé no es un diccionario "etimológico" per se. Si así fuera con [esta entrada](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RdqXU1H) tendríamos respuesta a [esta pregunta](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19203/5481) y creo que una cosa es que el término se use así o pueda ser diminutivo de otra cosa, pero el origen etimológico es otra historia. No explica porqué se les da ese nombre a esas cosas y es razón que se les de por ser diminutivos de algo.

Comment: @user, la propia entrada de la pregunta, que creo que es del DRAE dice "bebida alcohólica fuerte". Las fuentes citadas en la respuesta  dicen que las tropas tuvieron que tirar de recursos locales ante la falta de suministros, y en Cuba lo más fácil de encontrar era el ron. Entiendo que la vuelta a España de estas tropas los soldados popularizaron el uso de otros licores (preferidos, más abundantes, baratos,etc.) frente al ron, como el coñac o el anís.